# Is there a way to make a while loop repeat itself?

Tags: python

I am trying to make this guessing game using rudimentary python. It looks like this:

```
secret_number = 9
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < 3:
    guess_count += 1
    guess = int(input('Guess: '))
    if guess == secret_number:
        print('You got it!')
```

I want to set it up so it asks the user if they want to play again, and if it is yes, repeat the while loop. How would I go by this?

Comment: Put the whole thing in another `while` loop

Comment: Unrelated, I would use a `for` loop rather than keep track of `guess_count` explicitly. `for _ in range(guess_limit): ... `, with a `break` statement immediately after `print('You got it!')`.

Answer (score 1):

You could either place the whole thing in a while loop or create a function such as below and call the function if your repeat condition is met. This has the added bonus of your being able to call this part of the game from other parts of your code.

```
def game():
    secret_number = 9
    guess_count = 0
    guess_limit = 3

    while guess_count < 3:
        guess_count += 1
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
        if guess == secret_number:
            print('You got it!')
    if some_condtion_like_user_input is True:
        game()
```

If you want to avoid recursion, something like the below:

```
def game():

    finish = False

    while not finish:
        secret_number = 9
        guess_count = 0
        while guess_count < 3:
            guess_count += 1
            guess = int(input('Guess: '))
            if guess == secret_number:
                print('You got it!')

        repeat = input("Start again? Y/N: ")
        if repeat == "N":
            finish = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game()
```

Comment: With this approach, you will be wasting memory in each recursive call? It will not be a problem with a little program, but with a big one you could have bad memory usage if I am right

Comment: I see how this works, but the game does not appear on the terminal

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, however I'm just assuming from the OPs post that he is talking about a fairly limited console application style learning program. If you wanted to be memory sensitive, a loop would almost certainly be more efficient

Comment: There is zero need for recursion here... why complicate things?

Answer (score 1):

Use another loop:

```
secret_number = 9
guess_limit = 3

end = False

while not end:
    for _ in range(guess_limit): # Using for range() is more pythonic
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
        if guess == secret_number:
            print('You got it!')
            break
    
    if input("Play again? --> Yes/No") == "No":
        end = True
```

Comment: This worked up until the end, where if it was set to Y it would not repeat

Comment: Could be simplified a bit with `end = repeat == "No"`

Answer (score 0):

I would use Game class to decouple game logic from user input like this:

```
import random

class Game:
    def __init__(self, guess_limit=3):
        self.guess_limit = guess_limit
        self.secret_number = random.randint(1, 9)
        self.guesses = 0
        self.last_guess = None

    @property
    def over(self):
        return self.won or self.lost

    @property
    def won(self):
        return self.last_guess == self.secret_number

    @property
    def lost(self):
        return self.guesses >= self.guess_limit

    def guess(self, number):
        self.last_guess = number
        self.guesses += 1
    
def main():
    while True:
        game = Game()
        while not game.over:
            number = int(input("Guess: "))
            game.guess(number)

        if game.won:
            print("Congratulations!")
        else:
            print("Game over. You lost.")

        if input("Try again (y/n)? ") != 'y':
            print("Bye!")
            break

main()
```

I know it's a bit verbose but wanted to give OOP a try here :)

Answer (score 0):

Some conditions are missing

```py
secret_number = 9
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
isEnded = False
while not isEnded:
    while guess_count < 3:
        guess_count += 1
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
        if guess == secret_number:
            guess_count = 3
            print('You got it!')

    if input("Play again? --> Yes/No \n") == "No":
        isEnded = True
    else:
        guess_count = 0
```

Comment: This looks like you are suggesting an improvement to an existing answer. Soon you will be able to comment on existing answers and thus suggest improvements to their authors.